# Creating SplitView in Xcode 4.2

Tags: objective-c, ios-simulator, uisplitviewcontroller

I am working on Xcode 4.2 and i am trying to develop split view. The problem i am facing is in the loading of detail view according to the selection of any row in table view. I tried to follow some tutorial but all they made in the earlier version of xcode where split view template is available but not in xcode4.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend Paul Hegarty's Stanford lectures on iTunesU. They're really helpful and cover split views on the iPad with what I'm pretty sure is the latest version of Xcode